# (Keep orphans alive) How to map child entity to set parentID property to null on father delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In EF Code First: how do we map the child entity to set parentID property to null on father delete? (Keep orphans alive)

Example:

```
class FullGroup - ID, Name, IEnumerable<Machine>() Machines, etc....

class Machine - ID, Name, virtual FullGroup? (asnullable), int? FullGroupId, etc.....

this.HasOptional(t => t.FullGroup)
                .WithMany(t => t.Machines)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.FullGroupId);
```

I know that when I want to delete the father entry, if I load ONLY the father, and try to delete it, I get an exception (if fatherId is not nullable).... but if I also include (load) the children and then try to delete the father, things work. 
However, this is not what I am looking for.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable (like your case-`FullGroupId`), Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship. So you need to configure that, try this:

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.FullGroup)
            .WithMany(t => t.Machines)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.FullGroupId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I saw your update now,  yes, it works if the child enties are loaded into the context as well, not only the parent entity. For more info, you can check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html). EF will translate the delete you want to execute in sql commands like these:

```
exex sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[Machines] where ([Id]=@0)',N'@0 int',@0=1
exex sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[Machines] where ([Id]=@0)',N'@0 int',@0=2
exex sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[Machines] where ([Id]=@0)',N'@0 int',@0=3
--...
exex sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[FullGroups] where ([Id]=@0)',N'@0 int',@0=1
```

However, from the [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html) I share before (contextualized to  your scenario), you can see this:

> Since there are no `Machines`  in memory, there will be no client-side cascade delete, but the database should clean up any
>   orphaned `Machines` because of the cascade delete defined in the
>   database.
>   When run (delete a `FullGroup`), the only command sent to the database is one to delete the `FullGroup`. The database cascade delete will delete the related machines in response.

So, it is not necessary eager load the child entities if you configure cascade delete in your relationship, the DB should do the work

Comment: Well, I am not sure if this changed, but in EF4.0 I need to load the children as well, when I delete the father, otherwise, it will delete all the children (if I use cascadeOnDelete).

Comment: Hello @Dryadwoods, I have updated my answer. Check the last part, that should answer the doubt you expose in your comment